# About the u and u0 values from lmer in lme4 [R]

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, multi-level

I am learning mixed models from https://www.cmm.bris.ac.uk/lemma/login/index.php and this question is regarding an exercise in Module 5.

The data has 33,988 observations from 508 schools. The student data is the first level and the school is the second level. I run the null model

```
nullmodel <- lmer(score ~ (1|schoolid), data = mydata, REML = FALSE)
```

(I could not find an open access to the dataset. I guess since the question is more conceptual it should not matter)

Should the intercept estimate that we get by running the summary of the nullmodel not be equal to mean of the 'score'? I get the intercept estimate as 30.60 and the mean [mean(mydata$score)] as 31.09. The values are close but not same.

Also, is there an direct way to get u0, the school level residuals?

Answer (score 0):

Random intercept effect, u0, is normally distributed with mean 0 and variance of σ_u0^2.

The σ_u0^2 is between-school variance.

You can calculate σ_u0^2 using a direct way.

1. calculate the mean score of each school
2. calculate variance of these values

The variance is close to σ_u0^2.

Comment: I recommend REML method for final model fit since REML estimates are unbiased for the random effects.